# Treesitter in Neovim ChadNv not working, returns error

Tags: lua, neovim

I am new to vim. I downloaded Chadnv straight to my AppData/Local and it runs the first time. The only problem is this error keeps popping up and I don't know how to fix it.

```
packer.nvim: Error running config for nvim-treesitter: Failed to load parser: uv_dlopen: 
C:\Users\sadda\AppData\Local\nvim-data\site\pack\packer\opt\nvim-treesitter\parser\lua.so 
is not a valid Win32 application.^M
```

I donwloaded mingw, however, it is still returning an error. Please feel free to ask more questions

Answer (score 1):

I'm using "LazyVim" but I encountered the same problem.

What helped me is following a solution from [this nvim-treesitter issue](https://github.com/nvim-treesitter/nvim-treesitter/issues/4341) and changing an order of environment variables in the `PATH`, so I put MinGW bin folder above nvim bin folder in the `PATH`.

Comment: How did you do that on Windows, I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @Ruby, I went to "Edit the system environment variables" > "Environment variables" > "Path". There you can change order of variables in the "Path", so I selected minGW folder (C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\mingw\tools\install\mingw64\bin in my case) and moved it above nvim folder (C:\Program Files\Neovim\bin in my case)